# Bash script for moving directories only moving the content within directories

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to move some directories and files within said directories to a new directory, the code I am using utilises a for loop and checks the content of a txt file which is used to determine what it is we want to move. I only insert the directory names into the txt file.

The code only seems to move the content within the directories and not the directory and it's content.

```
#!/bin/bash

cp "files_for_moving.txt" /Users/johndoe/project/for_moving

cd /Users/johndoe/project/for_moving

FILESFORMOVING="files_for_moving.txt"

LINES=$(cat $FILESFORMOVING)

echo $LINES

for i in $LINES
        do
        echo 'running the mover script'
        cp -R $i/ ../simple_done_updated/


done

cd /Users/johndoe/project
```

Comment: Do you mean to "move" (you are using the cp - copy command) several directories into one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try removing the first `/` from:

```bash
cp -R $i/ ../simple_done_updated/
```

to:

```bash
cp -R $i ../simple_done_updated/
```